# The mystery of blind source stepping, or how F# behaves erratically on large source files

Tags: debugging, compilation, compiler-errors, f#, f#-4.0

I was testing whether I could rely on `__LINE__` to always return the correct value and created a large source file with many lines.

At some point, the inline function names (which get names like `fun@7564-1`, where 7564 is the line number) started counting from zero again.

After some research I noticed that:

- If your source code hits line 65536, any errors, messages, stacktraces start counting from zero
- `__LINE__` still returns the correct value
- Decorated names of inline functions start from zero again
- Compile time errors underline totally unrelated lines
- Stepping through with debugging goes over totally unrelated lines
- Setting a breakpoint on the actual line sets it on the "blind" line
- Tooltips over variables during debugging still show the correct value, and no tooltips appear in the "blind" spot.

To illustrate, with a bunch of newlines and the method being debugged being over line 65535, I managed to get a blind source stepping experience:

[image: Blind source stepping]

Is this 2<sup>16</sup> boundary deliberate or by accident? Is it a limit artificially imposed by F# or by the CLR or PDB format?

Note (1): I only tested this with F# 4.0, .NET 4.5 on Windows 7 and 2012, using VS 2015.
Note (2): I doubt this boundary will be hit often, unless perhaps for auto-generated source files (in C# I have some autogen'ed files that exceed this boundary).

*Update:* reported as a [bug to the FSharp team on Github here](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/758).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have tried to reproduce using large files, and this is also weird on my machine.
- In the GitHub repo, [Don Syme has replied and asked something about your source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/758#issuecomment-162242624). This might be a limitation of current Visual F#'s tool.

This appears to be a [confirmed bug in Visual F#](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/758), the bug report has a [full repro solution for download](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/files/56915/FSharpBug758-repro1.zip).

There's a [related issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/851) on large source files throwing `StackOverflowException` in Debug build, and [another related issue also throwing an SOE](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/779) on large lambda or entrypoint, but in any build.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried all that and before I posted my question, I created a separate, new project to repro and be sure it wasn't something caused by connected projects. Are you saying that you cannot repro it yourself, i.e. by creating a large file with blank (or otherwise) lines larger than 64k?

Comment: Apologize, and I have tried to reproduce a large source code>64K as you suggested. You're right, this is not the case of your source files. As Don has replied, it's the limitation of the Visual F# Tools.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have answered Don Syme and I have added a repro project to the bug report. In the process I found two other bugs, one causing a `StackOverflowException` inside `FSharp.Core.Compiler`.

Comment: I've updated your answer to reflect the current consensus and bug reported related to this issue. If you don't agree, please rollback or update. Tx for the help.

Comment: @Abel It's OK. I'm fine with your edits. You're welcome! :)